# Add image from applicationStorage directory

Tags: android, actionscript-3, animate-cc

i'm creating an as3 application for android and ios in animate cc.
My problem is that i can't add images to the stage from applicationStorageDIrectory, the only thing that i can do is to list them:

```
var desktop:File = 

File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("imgFlussi/set");
var files:Array = desktop.getDirectoryListing();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 trace(files[i].nativePath); // gets the path of the files
 trace(files[i].name);// gets the name
}
```

this is the code with i try to add the images : 
imgLoader =

```
imgLoader = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("imgFlussi/set/"+valImg+".jpg") as DisplayObject;
cont.addChild(imgLoader);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that **File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(...)** returns a **File** instance, not a **DisplayObject**. In order for this to work you need to create a **Loader** instance and actually load it from the file:

```
var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;
var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest;

aRequest.url = "app-storage:/imgFlussi/set/" + valImg + ".jpg";
aLoader.load(aRequest);
cont.addChild(aLoader);
```

Comment: this works in  the animate simulator but not in the phone, why? the error : Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.